# Can I book flights and two hotels on booking.com as a package holiday?

Tags: booking.com, package-holiday

I am planning a trip from London to Turku. I will stay for 2 nights in Turku and 1 night in Helsinki in order to catch an early flight home.

I have identified that the flights I want to take, and the hotels I want to stay, are all the cheapest on booking.com according to Google Travel.

As a result, if I can book them all together as a package, I can get ATOL protection. However, I can't work out how I can book two hotels, one in Turku and one in Helsinki, from the Booking.com package holiday user interface.

Is it possible for me to do that?

Comment: I had to look up what ATOL was.  perhaps you should edit a link into your question.

Comment: What did Booking.com say when you asked them how to do this?

Comment: I couldn't find out how to do that in the UI at all. It didn't have a button for me to add destinations.

Comment: @MichaelTsang unfortunately I'm pretty sure this isn't possible. I haven't found anything explicitly confirming that, but the fact there's no sign of any way to add destinations (while it's very easily done when searching for just flights) and that the FAQs don't include anything about multi-destination trips points strongly to it not being possible.

Comment: @ChrisH In such case will I be better off booking everything direct without the use of booking.com despite they are selling flights and hotels cheaper than the own websites?

The benefit of booking everything as a package is that if something goes wrong, the travel agency can help me to arrange alternatives.

Comment: @MichaelTsang that last sentence probably makes quite a few people laugh. OTAs are notoriously bad when it comes to handling changes and the like, and often complicate things a lot compared to direct booking with the airline or hotel. We’ve seen way to many cases here of travellers stuck between the OTA and airline bouncing the hot potato to each other.

Comment: It's well known OTAs are notoriously bad when it comes to handling changes, so if I book everything alone and separately I book direct.

However, when it's a package holiday, things are different.

Comment: @ChrisH On re-read, I agree that ATOL isn't the right target. Thanks for pointing it out; I'll delete my comment.

Comment: There is a screenshot in this article https://www.which.co.uk/news/article/should-i-book-my-next-holiday-with-booking-com-afR3Z4f7Tw1w that shows a ‘flight + hotel’ option but I can’t find it on the website. I suspect Booking.com offers some limited package deals, but doesn’t do a full ‘put your itinerary together’ type service